# Cannot be applied to '(java.lang.string, int)'

Tags: java, android, database

This is my codes:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wttZ5.png)

I used getMotorcycleId to post motorcycle_id(int) to database, but i got that error, but when i commented on that line, i got another error like this:
[problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGPdn.png)

Thank you all!

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Body parameters are expected to be Strings, but you're returning an int, so your IDE is warning you of a type mismatch that will prevent compilation. Use String.valueOf(newBooking.getMotorcycleID()) and String.valueOf(newBooking.getSelectedService()) instead to get equivalent String representations of these ints.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on the images you shared.
First Image.
`newBooking.getMotorcycleID` here in Booking class getMotorcycleId returning int value and
`addBodyParameter("motorcycle_id",newBooking.getMotorcycleID);` this needs string value.
you can change it to `addBodyParameter("motorcycle_id",String.ValueOf(newBooking.getMotorcycleID));` this will work or by changing return type to string in Booking class you can over come this problem.

Even Second image has same issue. check the data type and convert it to string if needed.

Comment: is not a problem when is send string while my motorcycle_id on my database is int?

Comment: while inserting to database you can again change it to `Integer.parseInt(newBooking.getMotorcycleID)` or you can change data type of your id in database to String(which is bad habbit).

Answer (score -1):

the `newBooking.getSelectedService()` return value is not a string and it cause to show the error which you need to convert the value to `String` or append it to an empty `String`:

```
addBodyParameter("motorcycle_id", newBooking.getMotorcycleID + "");
addBodyParameter("motorcycle_id", String.ValueOf(newBooking.getMotorcycleID));
```

if the value is an integer:

```
addBodyParameter("motorcycle_id", Integer.toString(newBooking.getMotorcycleID));
```

Answer (score -1):

Body Parameter mismatched. newBooking.getMotorcycleID() is returning int but addBodyParameter function accepts second argument as String. You should convert it into String using String.valueOf()